# Azure Caching ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0009> Exeeded Quota Limits for this hour

Tags: azure, distributed-caching

I'm working on an MVC 3 site which is hosted in Windows Azure that is configured to use the DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider for session state which, in turn, uses Azure caching internally.  The cache is configured as:

```
<dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <hosts>
    <host name="test.cache.windows.net" cachePort="XXXX" />
  </hosts>
  <securityProperties mode="Message">
    <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="XXXX">
    </messageSecurity>
  </securityProperties>
  <transportProperties receiveTimeout="45000" />
</dataCacheClient>
 </dataCacheClients>
```

The session provider is configured as

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" useBlobMode="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

We've had this in place since April but just recently started using the session to store a little bit more data.  Our test caching service is 128 MB, which is said to allow 5 concurrent connections.  The most we've used of this service at any given time, according to the Azure management console, is 0.34 MB.

In our logs we're seeing this exception appear quite often:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (The request failed, because you exceeded quota limits for this hour. If you experience this often, upgrade your subscription to a higher one). Additional Information : Throttling due to resource : Connections

According to the documentation I've read, the data cache client by default has maximum connections set to 1.  I'm running on two instances, which I assume would mean I'm using two total connections.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not throttled just on storage usage. You're also throttled on transactions per hour and bandwidth per hour. For a 128MB cache:

- 400,000 transactions per hour
- 1,400 MB bandwidth per hour

Might you be running into one of these two boundary conditions?

For more details around AppFabric Cache SLA, look at this [MSDN blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602420.aspx#CACHING_FAQ).

Comment: +1 I agree, If it has been working for some time then it is likely to be one of these reasons.  Try increasing your cache size.

Comment: While I realize I can increase my cache size, I have a hard time understanding how I could have reached quota limits.  We had 4 people testing that probably access the Session a total of no more than 200 times (it was about a 5 minute period going through a specific process).  We've escalated to Microsoft.  Will update when root cause is identified.

Comment: We're not pursuing this anymore and have decided to move away from the Azure caching service.  The idea that once you reach quota limits you're denied usage until an hourly reset is not an acceptable risk for us.  Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: Jeff - I'm also experiencing the same problem. I'm wondering what your alternative solution was. Thanks!